# How to Center All of the Lines of Long Text Insertions in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, center, protected-macro

Consider the code which has no problem centering short text insertions in the TOC:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\hfil\protect {\Large{\textbf{PART I.}}} \hfil}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 12pt \par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hfil\protect {\Large{\textbf{HERE IS A CENTERED TOC ENTRY.}}} \hfil}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 45pt \par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hfil\protect {\Large{\textbf{HERE IS A ANOTHER TOC ENTRY THAT I WANT CENTERED AS WELL---BUT THIS IS WHAT I GET.}}} \hfil}
\end{document}
```

and which produces the output:

[image]

As one can see, the code nicely centers the TOC text entries which are not forced onto a subsequent line; however, the longer entry which in this case takes up three lines in the TOC is not centered in all of its three lines in the TOC, though I used the same commands that centered the shorter ones.

QUESTION: How may I modify the code to handle longer TOC entries; i.e., those that extend onto at least one additional line such that all the lines in the TOC are automatically centered?

Thank you.

Comment: `\protect {\Large{` never apply `\protect to `{` and`\Large` does not take an argument (which I am sure I have mentioned before:-)

Comment: @David Carlisle Thank you. I am sure you have. I see from your answer how to handle such sizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\centering` not `\hfil` to centre a paragraph, also size commands do not take an argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{{\centering\Large\bfseries PART I.\par}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\par\vspace{12pt}}
\addtocontents{toc}{{\centering\Large\bfseries HERE IS A CENTERED TOC ENTRY.\par}}

\addtocontents{toc}{\par\vspace{45pt}}
\addtocontents{toc}{{\centering\Large\bfseries HERE IS A ANOTHER TOC ENTRY THAT I WANT CENTERED AS WELL---BUT THIS IS WHAT I GET.\par}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am confident from your output that it works on your end. Unfortunately, when I run it, it abends, indicating `Extra}, or forgotten endgroup. ...`  I cannot find an extra `}` anywhere. Do you have any idea of what may be going wrong on my end? Many thanks.

Comment: you copied it wrong or you have a corrupted aux or toc file that you could delete or something else @mlchristians

Comment: Thanks. I'll check on that.